# Probability of a train journey

Tags: probability

A trip from south east London to Southampton consists of three journeys:

bus journey to Crystal Palace station, train journey from Crystal Palace to Clapham Junction, train
journey from Clapham Junction to Southampton.

Each journey can be delayed (d) or on
time (o) with the following probabilities:

For the bus journey to Crystal Palace station: P(d)=2/3 and P(o)=1/3

For the train journey from Crystal Palace to Clapham Junction: P(d)=1/4 and P(o)=3/4

For the train journey from Clapham Junction to Southampton: P(d)=1/4 and P(o)=3/4

The lateness or not of any transport is independent of the lateness or not of any other
transport.

a) You may miss a train if the journey before it is delayed (irrespective of whether the
train itself is also delayed). Calculate the probability that a train may be missed.

b) Find the probability that the train from Crystal Palace to Clapham Junction is
delayed, given that the bus journey is delayed.

**My Attempt**

a) I created a sample space: {ddd,doo,dod,odo,ddo,odd}
I added multiplied the elements together then added them up but I was slightly confused because couldn't {ddd,ddo} occur twice? For example the first train can be delayed but also the second is delayed so you could miss the second or the third train so would you need to count these ones twice?

Anyways I wasn't sure so I didn't count them twice and got 5/8

b) If the lateness of not of any transport is independe of the lateness or not of any other transport, would this not mean that the answer is just 0?

Comment: If independent, then the probability is $1/4$.

Comment: Wouldn't be easier to talk about trip $A$, $B$, and $C$? To be honest I always get lost when in Rome...

Comment: Check you sample space for completeness.

Answer (score 1):

The sample space with the (product) probabilities assigned to the elementary events:

$$
\begin {matrix}
\text{#}&\text{bus}&\text{train1}&\text{train2}&\text{prod. of probs.}&\text{resulting prob}\\
1&\text{O}&\text{O}&\text{O}&\frac{1}{3}\frac{3}{4}\frac{3}{4}&\frac{9}{48}\\
2&\text{O}&\text{O}&\text{D}&\frac{1}{3}\frac{3}{4}\frac{1}{4}&\frac{3}{48}\\
3&\text{O}&\text{D}&\text{O}&\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{4}\frac{3}{4}&\frac{3}{48}\\
4&\text{O}&\text{D}&\text{D}&\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{4}&\frac{1}{48}\\
5&\text{D}&\text{O}&\text{O}&\frac{2}{3}\frac{3}{4}\frac{3}{4}&\frac{18}{48}\\
6&\text{D}&\text{O}&\text{D}&\frac{2}{3}\frac{3}{4}\frac{1}{4}&\frac{6}{48}\\
7&\text{D}&\text{D}&\text{O}&\frac{2}{3}\frac{1}{4}\frac{3}{4}&\frac{6}{48}\\
8&\text{D}&\text{D}&\text{D}&\frac{2}{3}\frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{4}&\frac{2}{48}\\
&&&&\text{Total:}&1
\end{matrix}
$$

---

$$P(\text{A train is missed.})=P(3)+P(4)+P(5)+P(6)+P(7)+P(8)=\frac{3+1+18+6+6+2}{48}=\frac{36}{48}=\frac{3}{4}.$$

---

$$P(\text{The train from Cr. P. to Cl. J. is delayed}|\text{The bus journey is delayed.})=$$
$$=\frac{P(\text{The train from Cr. P. to Cl. J. is delayed. AND The bus journey is delayed.)}}{\text{P(The bus journey is delayed.)}}=\frac{P(7)+P(8)}{P(5)+P(6)+P(7)+P(8)}=$$
$$=\frac{\frac{6}{48}+\frac{2}{48}}{\frac{18}{48}+\frac{6}{48}+\frac{6}{48}+\frac{2}{48}}=\frac{8}{32}=\frac{1}{4}.$$

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have made a mistake in asking the question; in the distinction between independent and dependent. That is if I properly identified your intention if not disregard the above statement.

My answer to you questions part A and B as they are written:

Answer A: 2/3+1/4=11/12 The likelihood of one or more out of a series of independent happenings occurring is additive.

train from Crystal Palace to Clapham Junction = Train-1

train from Clapham Junction to Southampton = Train-2

If the bus is late you will miss the departure of Train-1.  If Train-1 is late you will miss the departure of Train-2.  If Train-2 is late it is irrelevant because if the bus and Train-1 were on time causing you to be waiting at claphan Junction before it arrived; thus making it impossible for you to miss train-2.

The likelihood that you will miss Train-1 or Train-2 because of the delays that may occur on the bus or Train-1 is 11/12; In other words out of every twelve attempts to ride this route to its final destination you will probably miss Train-1 or Train-2 a total of 11 times.

Answer B: You stated this in the governing rules of the question "The lateness or not of any transport is independent of the lateness of any other transport"
"Meaning that regardless of the lateness or not of the bus the Train from Crystal Palace to Clapham Junction(Train-1) would be subjected only to its own independent risk of being delayed which is stated as 1/4 or a 25% chance of occurring for each attempt to take this route.

Q.E.D

http://www.wyzant.com/resources/lessons/math/statistics_and_probability/probability/further_concepts_in_probability